# What would you call someone who is there if you need him but who is not imposing?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am sitting in a restaurant and the waiter is available for me if I call him.  He is there but not imposing. In a high end restaurant, the waiter would be serving while maintaining the quietness and comfort of the  restaurant's atmosphere. What would be an appropriate adjective to describe the waiter?

Comment: I would call that a "reliable person", though I suspect you're looking for just one word for such a person.  I feel as though this question has already been asked elsewhere, though I cannot recall where at the moment.

Comment: I did not mean a reliable person. I have been searching and I think subtle would be what I was looking for, though I am not sure if I can call a person subtle

Comment: I think you need to make that intent a bit more obvious in the question then.  It sounds as though you're asking about someone who helps without being overbearing, rather than a helpful but unnoticed person.

Comment: Perhaps an alternative to subtle would be [unobtrusive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unobtrusive) - not conspicuous or attracting attention.  It is common to see highly regarded waiters referred to as ["attentive and unobtrusive."](https://www.google.com/search?q=attentive+and+unobtrusive&oq=attentive+and+unobtrusive&aqs=chrome..69i57.3707j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about ***"[Unobtrusive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unobtrusive)"***?

Or perhaps "***[Inconspicuous](http://thesaurus.com/browse/inconspicuous)***."

Comment: Thats it exactly. I meant inconspicuous

Answer (score 4):

It may not be a perfect match in all situations but **Attentive**, could work especially in terms of service.

The OED definiton of 
**Attentive**

adjective

paying close attention to something:

*never before had she had such an attentive audience*

*ministers should be more attentive to the interests of taxpayers*

**assiduously attending to the comfort or wishes of others; very polite or courteous:**

*the hotel has a pleasant atmosphere and attentive service*

Comment: Upvoted since  *attentive* is relevant; however, *attentive* is questionable as it suggests hovering, which is tantamount to imposing.

Comment: When we talk of good,attentive service esp in the Hospitality business the implication is unobtrusive.It is a part of the training process and a given to the customer.The explanation may not fall in the purview of English Language per se, but here I feel the word is apt.